# Remove group ownership of a directory

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I'm creating a [page](https://blog.arturofm.com/ghost/#/editor/post/5e4219bba458cd09d8b11c94) with all the commands I use or need but I can't find how to remove a group ownership of a directory, all the pages show how to add it, but how do you remove it? Let's say I have a dir called myFolder, and the group admin owns it, how can I leave the folder with no group ownership?

I know to add is like: `chown -hR myGroup: /var/www`

Thanks

EDIT:
Let me put it more clear, I have a folder with this permissions:
`drwxr-xr-x 2 arturo root`
How can I remove/get out/eliminate/disappear arturo from there and leave it how it came out when I create it? I gess root root

Comment: "remove" group ownership? You can't "remove".

Comment: Every directory has a user and a group owner.  You can't add or remove it, you can only change it to something else.  Probably the closest thing to what you're asking would be to create a group with no members, and `chgrp` the directory to that group.

Comment: What does this have to do with programming? There are better groups for this question at https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: @KamilCuk see my edit above

Comment: @NateEldredge see my edit above

Comment: This directory is owned by user `arturo` and group `root`.  You can change the user and/or the group to whatever you want using `chown` and `chgrp` respectively, but the directory always has to be owned by a user and a group.  It sounds like you want to change the user back to the user who created the directory.  You'll need to find out which user that was (possibly `root`?) and use `chown` to change the directory's ownership to that user.  But figuring that out is up to you - the system does not store information about previous owners.

Comment: Anyway, I don't think this is a programming question, and it should be closed as off topic.  It would make more sense at http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to reset the directory's ownership to root, then you can use this command:

```sh
chown root:root /var/www -R
```

Answer (score 0):

You unable to just remove ownership. In the Unix/Linux, any file or directory must belong to some group. However, you can change group owner to `nobody`, or create special group, for example - `dummy`, and change ownership to that group.

To add a new group, you can use command `groupadd` (Linux) or `pw groupadd` (FreeBSD).

Comment: see my edit above